# Invalid IL code error in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, perlin-noise

I'm trying to use perlin noise to generate terain using Unity3D (version 5.0.2f1) but I  get this error:

```
InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in TerrainGenerator:GenerateFloor (): IL_0045: call      0x0a00000c


TerrainGenerator.Generate () (at Assets/TerrainGenerator.js:36)
TerrainGenerator.Start () (at Assets/TerrainGenerator.js:23)
```

Code:

```
function GenerateFloor(){
    print("The function was called");
    if(!(seed > 0)){
        Debug.LogError("Seed not valid. Seed: " + seed + " .");
        seed = Random.Range(0, 1000000000000000);
        Debug.LogError("Generated new seed. Seed: " + seed + ".");
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < heightMap.length; i++){
        if(currentX == Math.Sqrt(size)){
            currentX = 0;
            currentZ++;
        }
        else if(currentX > Math.Sqrt(size)) Debug.LogError("How did this happen?! currentX = " + currentX + " size = " + size + " .");
        var height = Mathf.PerlinNoise(currentX, currentZ);
        heightMap[currentX * currentZ] = new Vector3(currentX, height, currentZ);
        print("For loop worked");
        //yield;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you specify, where do you get this error? In the editor when it compiles the script? Or when you try to build for target platform? Or when you start the game in editor? Also, in the error I see `TerrainGenerator.Generate () (at Assets/TerrainGenerator.js:36)` and `TerrainGenerator.Start () (at Assets/TerrainGenerator.js:23)`, but in code you provide there are not methods named `Generate` or `Start`. Could you provide them as well?

Comment: Btw, probably not the issue, but your param 1000000000000000 in Random.Range is excessively beyond maximum. Maybe you want `int.MaxValue` ? which would be 2147483647.

Comment: @peterept Believe it or not, that was indeed the issue. It works now. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: haha. excellent. It is worth filing that with Unity as a bug.

Comment: I wrote up an answer below for anyone else stumbling into a similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your param 1000000000000000 in Random.Range is excessively beyond maximum. Maybe you want int.MaxValue ? which would be 2147483647

Interesting it caused such a compiler error with IL2CPP !